# How to debug c ncurses program with keyboard input on Ubuntu and VS Codium

Tags: c, gdb, ncurses, tty, gdbserver

I tried to find out how it is best do debug a c ncurses program with keyboard input.
From all of the methods it worked best for me, to use gdbserver and an extra terminal.

It is important, that the terminal is in full screen when the program starts.

The problem is, that the keyboard input in the extra gdbserver terminal does not work.
Did I do something wrong or is it generally not possible to get the keyboard inputs working with gdbserver?

With gdb externalConsole in "launch.json" the keyboard input worked, but the external console does not start in full screen and I did not find a option to start the windows in full screen.

If so, what alternatives can debug a c ncurses program with keyboard input?

Side Information: The program also has multiple threads.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (jammy) and vs codium.
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz

Thanks

I tried the instructions of this website:
https://www.fayewilliams.com/2014/11/11/debug-ncurses-with-gdb-gdbserver-and-full-input-output/

I tried gdb tty debugging:
[GDB - Display output of target application in a separate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963208/gdb-display-output-of-target-application-in-a-separate-window)

I tried gdb with external console:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

EDIT: The debugging via external console does not work with console!

Comment: Why not just [`attach`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Attach.html) to the running process?

Comment: Run the program in a terminal. Attach a gdb session running in another terminal. No gdbserver or json or GUI necessary.

Comment: Would setting the `stopAtEntry` setting to `true` be sufficient when using an external console? That would break into the program right at the beginning and allow you to maximize the launched external console manually before commencing. Another option may be to do not launch an external console, but set `miDebuggerArgs` to use the `-t devicename` option (where `devicename` is the path to the tty where the program is to run).

Comment: `strace` could help here. That's how I recently debugged a text editor. Run *strace -p pid* in another window.

Comment: If you can't attach there is another way to debug it with `tty` command, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16304989/72178.